# Find multiple variables (multiple conditions) in list - SQL

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join, teradata, where-clause

I have to find transactions which are not ***INTERNAL*** and count the SUM of their EURO_AMOUNT values.

> ***INTERNAL*** *- Account_to and Account_from belongs to one customer*

In this case ***result*** should be: (EURO_AMOUNT) 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 7 = **21**

Thats simplified model of my DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transaction_details` (
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `euro_amount` int(6) NOT NULL,
    `account_from` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `account_to` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `account` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

And thats simplified data.

```
INSERT INTO `transaction_details` (`id`,`euro_amount`, `account_from`, `account_to`, `customer_id`)
VALUES 
    ('1','1', 'Account1', 'Account2', '10'), -- Internal
    ('2','2', 'Account3', 'Account4', '11'),
    ('3','3', 'Account1', 'Account3', '12'),
    ('4','4', 'Account1', 'Account4', '13'),
    ('5','5', 'Account1', 'Account3', '10'),
    ('6','6', 'Account15', 'Account1', '10'), -- Internal
    ('7','7', 'Account15', 'Account3', '10'); 

INSERT INTO `customer` (`id`, `customer_id`, `account`)
VALUES 
    ('1', '10', 'Account1'),
    ('2', '11', 'Account3'),
    ('3', '12', 'Account4'),
    ('4', '10', 'Account2'),
    ('5', '10', 'Account15');
```

From 'programming language' perspective, I think one idea could be something more or less like this:

```
fun getAccountsForCustomer(customer_id): List<Account>
```

```
fun main() {
       List<Transaction_Detail> transactions;
       transactions.stream()
                   .filter(transaction -> {
                     if(transaction.account_from IN getAccountsForCustomer(transaction.customer_id) 
                        AND transaction.account_to IN getAccountsForCustomer(transaction.customer_id)) {
                         return 0;
                      } else {
                         return transaction;
                  }
       }).reduce((a,b) -> a+b);
    }
```

But this is from 'programming language' perspective and not from SQL :/

Appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the transactions details, you can join the customers table twice (once for `account_from` and once for `account_to`) and filter out those that have the same `customer_id`. The final step is aggregation:

```
select sum(td.euro_amount) sum_euro_amount
from transaction_details td
inner join customer c1 on c1.account = td.account_from
inner join customer c2 on c2.account = td.account_to
where c1.customer_id <> c2.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Join twice to compare the customer and aggregate:

```
select sum(td.amount)
from transaction_details td join
     customer cto
     on ct.account = td.account_to
     customer cfrom
     on cfrom.account = td.account_from
where ct.customer_id <> cfrom.customer_id
```